# Replacing 2D sub-array in 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have following 3D array (shape = (3,3,3)):

```
a = array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Now I want to replace e.g. the 0'th 2D layer within the 3D array with the 2D array

```
b = array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]])
```

, such that

```
a = array([[[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]],
       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I could use np.insert(a,0,b,axis=0) and subsequently delete the last 2D layer in the 3D array but that doesn't seem to be elegant.

Comment: Can't you just do `a[0] = b` or am I missing something

Comment: @Moosefeather you are absolutely right. I messed up with the indexing -.-. My fault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
b = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]])
a[0] = b
a
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Cheers